# Arity mismatch with Java Cucumber data tables

Tags: java, cucumber

I've been learning Cucumber for Java using [Jakub Czeczótka's great blog](http://blog.czeczotka.com/2014/07/22/cucumber-jvm-with-maven-in-minutes/).  But he lost me when describing data tables.
I made a calculator class with addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division.  Individual tests of each of those methods pass.  When I try to use a table, I get an arity mismatch error from Gherkin:

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Arity mismatch: Step Definition 'com.test.bdd.steps.CalculatorSteps.iWantToPerformADataTableCalculation(DataTable) in file: .../Code/Java/CucumberTest/target/test-classes/' with pattern [^I want to perform a data table calculation$] is declared with 1 parameters. However, the gherkin step has 0 arguments [].
```

Here are the relevant files and paths:

```
src/main/java/com/test/bdd/calculator/
package com.test.bdd.calculator;
public class Calculator
{

    private int result;
    public void divide( int a, int b )
    {
        result = a / b;
    }
    public int getResult()
    {
        return result;
    }
}


src/test/resources/cucumber/
  Scenario: Division
    Given I want to perform a calculation
    When I divide 14 by 2
    Then the result should be 7

  Scenario Outline: Division Data Table
    Given I want to perform a data table calculation
    When I divide <Numerator> by <Divisor>
    Then the result should be <Result>
    Examples:
      | Numerator | Divisor | Result |
      | 100       | 2       | 50     |
      | 100       | 4       | 25     |
      | 1000      | 200     | 5      |


src/test/java/com/test/bdd/steps/
package com.test.bdd.steps;
public class CalculatorSteps
{
    private Calculator calculator;
    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {
        calculator = new Calculator();
    }

    @When( "^I divide <Numerator> by <Divisor>$" )
    public void iDivideNumeratorByDivisor()
    {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        calculator.divide( 4, 3 );
    }


    @Then( "^the result should be <Result>$" )
    public void theResultShouldBeResult()
    {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        assertEquals( 1, calculator.getResult() );
    }


    @Given( "^I want to perform a data table calculation$" )
    public void iWantToPerformADataTableCalculation( DataTable table )
    {
        if( table != null )
        {
            for ( Map<String, Integer> map : table.asMaps( String.class, Integer.class ) )
            {
                Integer numerator = map.get( "Numerator" );
                Integer divisor = map.get( "Divisor" );
                Integer result = map.get( "Result" );
                System.out.println( format( "Dividing %d by %d yields %d", numerator, divisor, result ) );
            }
        }
    }
}


package com.test.bdd.runner;
@RunWith( Cucumber.class )
@CucumberOptions(
    glue = "com.test.bdd.steps",
    features = "classpath:cucumber/calculator.feature" )


public class RunCalculatorTests
{
}
```

So my table does not seem to be getting to Gherkin.  I presume my map has problems as well, but will deal with that when I get past the arity issue.
What do I need to do to resolve this arity mismatch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no DataTable for this step of the scenario in the feature file. There is no requirement to add a DataTable argument to this stepdefinition.

This example seems to highlights the use of a ScenarioOutline rather than that of a DataTable.

ScenarioOutline defines a set of steps, so far similar to a scenario. Now these steps can be executed repeatedly using the data from the examples table. Each row of this table corresponds to one execution of the steps described. So if u have 3 rows there will be 3 runs.

On the other hand DataTable is uses to send data as a kind of list to a specific step of a scenario. Like maybe a shopping list. This is run only once. Though it can be used in a ScenarioOutline also, thus allowing u to use variable lists

Comment: Grasshopper, I noticed that I did not have a regex to capture the values in my step file.  How should I modify that to fix this?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Can you add more details

Answer (score 1):

ArityMismatch means that you are not passing the right number of parameters.
For instance:

```
@When( "^I divide <Numerator> by <Divisor>$" )
public void iDivideNumeratorByDivisor()
{
```

The step uses 2 parameters (numerator and divisor), but the method does not specify these parameters.

Use something like this instead:
    @When( "^I divide  by $" )
    public void iDivideNumeratorByDivisor(int num, int div)
    {